# When using libraries taken from Github, where should I put the Apache license?

Tags: license-recommendation, attribution, license-file

I downloaded few source codes for android from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Game/List_of_Free_code_Game.htm).

From what I see this website doesn't state the license of these source codes anywhere, although the title say free code game and it says open source in the url, I can't find a txt file in the apps or a line in the website stating the license for these projects.

I want to modify these apps and upload them to play store, or sell them, the problem is that I don't know if I have the right to do this or not. above this, when using libraries with apache license, I don't know if the whole app will be considered under this license or just the parts used.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is answered right on their site's footer:

> Demo Source and Support. All rights reserved.

This line (*All rights reserved.*) is a vague and general assertion statement which tries to assert all possible rights on the code/software to the copyright holder. This essentially means that you have ZERO rights to use the downloaded code or software besides an academic study and experimentation. If the said source-code is indeed open-source, you will typically find a `LICENSE` file distributed along with your source-code because most [FOSS licenses](http://opensource.org/licenses/) have a clause that allows (or sometimes even requires in case of GPL/LGPL) the distributor to include that `LICENSE` while giving you the code.

Furthermore, this `LICENSE` file contains the usual text that grants YOU, the user, all rights to the software. The templates for these texts are usually one of the standard OSI approved FOSS licenses such as GPL (GNU General Public License), Apache, MIT, Mozilla, etc.